# Overloading arithmetic operators in C++

Tags: c++

Statements:

```
myVec[2] = myVec[0] + myVec[1];
cout<<myVec[2]<<endl;
myVec[2] = myVec[0] - myVec[1];
cout<<myVec[2]<<endl;
```

Output:

```
[Node::Add] [0] + [1] = {X = 14.9} {Y = 11.7} {Z = 9.4}
[Node::Sub] [0] - [1] = {X = 14.9} {Y = 11.7} {Z = 9.4}
```

The above is printed out by the console after using the next two functions in sequence. The problem is that the value of the [2] index being printed does not change when the overloaded operator '-' is called.

```
Vector_t operator+(const Vector_t &other) const {
   Vector_t rv;

   rv.x = this->x + other.x;
   rv.y = this->y + other.y;
   rv.z = this->z + other.z;

   return rv;
}

Vector_t operator-(const Vector_t& other) const {
   Vector_t rv;

   rv.x = this->x - other.x;
   rv.y = this->y - other.y;
   rv.z = this->z - other.z;

   return rv;
}
```

The set of data that I am using can be seen here:

```
myVec[0].setX(5.8);
myVec[0].setY(7.3);
myVec[0].setZ(6.2);

myVec[1].setX(9.1);
myVec[1].setY(4.4);
myVec[1].setZ(3.2);
```

It's more than likely that the issue stems from my call type, but I am unsure.

Comment: Add the code where you add the vectors.

Comment: myVec[2] = myVec[0] + myVec[1];
cout<<myVec[2]<<endl;
myVec[2] = myVec[0] - myVec[1];
cout<<myVec[2]<<endl;

Comment: I am not quite sure, but look at your two functions , the & symbol is at different places. Try moving the ampersand.

Comment: @Evcan Mustafa I have actually moved the ampersand quite a bit and cannot get the output to change. It may also be important to add that the values do change appropriately when I comment out the call to the overloaded '+' operator. So the functions are doing what they are supposed to do, but when called one after another, the second - and presumably the following - fail.

Comment: what's your operator[] implementation?

Comment: Did you happen to overload `operator=` as well?

Comment: `[Node::Add] [0] + [1] =` where is this printed?